# How to send an image message only ? (without sending a text as well)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-gifted-chat

I simply want to send an image without typing any text ?
I am using react-native-image-picker and i currently can send an image with a text , but what if i want to send an image only ?
I tried alwaysShowSend and try to send but nothing happens unless the text field is not empty
The docs are very vague on this ...

```
      <GiftedChat
        messages={friendMsgs}
        onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages, this.state.image)}
        user={{
          _id: user && user.id,
          name: user && user.firstName,
          avatar: user && user.profilemage
        }}
        text={this.state.text}
        alwaysShowSend={
          this.state.text ? true : false || this.state.image ? true : false
        }
        onInputTextChanged={text => this.setState({ text })}
        renderLoading={() => <Loading />}
        onLoadEarlier={this.loadMessages.bind(this, userParams)}
        isLoadingEarlier={loading}
        isAnimated
        renderAvatarOnTop
        loadEarlier={friendMsgs.length >= 20}
        scrollToBottom
        scrollToBottomComponent={() => (
          <Ionic name='ios-arrow-round-down' size={30} color='#000' />
        )}
        extraData={this.state}
        renderBubble={props => {
          const color = props.currentMessage.read ? '#0084ff' : '#389bff';
          return (
            <Bubble
              {...props}
              wrapperStyle={{ right: { backgroundColor: color } }}
            />
          );
        }}
        renderActions={() => (
          <Feather
            style={styles.uploadImage}
            onPress={this.uploadImage}
            name='image'
            size={30}
            color='#000'
          />
        )}
      />


  onSend(messages = [], image) {
    const { socket, user, navigation } = this.props;
    const { friendMsgs } = this.props.history;

    const receiver = navigation.getParam('user');

    if (socket && socket.readyState === 1) {
      const msg = {
        ...messages[0],
        image
      };

      const sendMsg = GiftedChat.append(friendMsgs, msg);

      const data = {
        senderId: user && user.id,
        receiverType: 'user',
        messageType: 'text',
        receiverId: receiver.id,
        read: false,
        content: messages[0].text
      };

      this.props.sendMsg(data, sendMsg);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```js
 const msg = {
     createdAt: new Date(),
     user: user && user.id,
     image: image,
     sent: true,
     received: true,
   }
...
const sendMsg = GiftedChat.append(friendMsgs, msg);
const data = {
        senderId: user && user.id,
        receiverType: 'user',
        receiverId: receiver.id,
        read: false,
      };

      this.props.sendMsg(data, sendMsg);
this.props.sendMsg({});
```

Comment: No, the onsend function itself doesn't get invoked unless the text field is not empty

Comment: @AmrAboElenin I've modified the correct answer. Would you like to try?

Comment: Thanks for your help , but the problem is with the onSend function itself being invoked if the text field is not empty.

Comment: @AmrAboElenin Can't you call when the text field is not empty but not empty?

Comment: @AmrAboElenin You said you wanted to send images without text. But you're saying you can't page with text. When text is not empty, it means there is text.

Answer (score 1):

This came up in a project for me recently. I created my own `Send` component which started off as a duplicate of `react-native-gifted-chat-send/lib/utils/Send`.

I modified the `handleOnPress` function definition to check if a file has been attached, and allow the message to be sent if either a file is present or the message isn't blank.

This new send component is then attached to `GiftedChat` through the `renderSend` property.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to make the custom send button, to do this:

```
import { GiftedChat, Send } from 'eact-native-gifted-chat';
```

and then in your component make this function:

```
//Where onSend is the function use to onsend;
  const customSendPress = (text, onSend) => {
    if (image && !text && onSend) {
      onSend({text: text.trim()}, true);
    } else if (text && onSend) {
      onSend({text: text.trim()}, true);
      0;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

and finally create customSend button.
const customSend = ({onSend, text, sendButtonProps, ...sendProps}) => {
return (
<Send
{...sendProps}
textStyle={styles.sendButton}
sendButtonProps={{
...sendButtonProps,
onPress: () => customSendPress(text, onSend),
}}
/>
);
};

and finally update your GiftedChat component.

```
<GiftedChat
        messages={messages}
        onSend={(msg) => onSend(msg)}
        user={{
          _id: auth().currentUser.uid,
        }}
        renderSend={customSend}
        alwaysShowSend
        placeholder={image ? 'Add Caption' : 'Type your message'}
        renderLoading={() => {
          return <Loader />;
        }}
        renderTicks={customTicks}
      />
```

This will allow you to send only message with image (with caption or without caption).

Answer (score 0):

I did a little workaround for this,
When the image is selected and the text is empty, i simply set the text to an empty space that way the onSend function works without needing to send any text with the image!.

```
this.setState({ text: ' ' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bypass this by using this workaround

```
    text={(this.state.recordingUri && "Audio") ||
          (this.state.image && "Image")
    }
```

You can give empty string if you want.